# Import Error: cannot import name 'APIKEY' from 'apikey'

Tags: python-3.x, api-key

I installed the `apikey` package (using Anaconda prompt) but I still get this error: "Import Error: cannot import name 'APIKEY' from 'apikey'".

I have tried to restart kernel but it didn't help.

I am trying to connect to ChatGPT API, other ways to do so may also help.

python version 3.8.8.

apikey detials:

[image: apikey detials]